# Install Win32 module to python 2.6

Tags: python

I want to use win32com module  with python26. By default there is no win32 module available for python26. How will i get it to install in my machine.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at easy_install. With that, you can (as the name suggests) easily install any library not included with Python.

The installation page for easy_install is here. 
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools

Once you've followed the installation instructions for your particular OS, make sure that you've added Python to your Path, so that you can run it from cmd. You can look up how to do this.

Having done all that, you can install win32com by opening the command prompt and typing:

```
easy_install win32com
```

You can do this for other libraries as well, like mechanize and BeautifulSoup.